# Is it possible to print DOS characters on a website?

Tags: html, unicode

I would like to print some kind of ASCII "art" on a web page in pre-tags. These graphics use DOS characters to show a map like old maze games did. I didn't find anything in the HTML special character reference. Is there a way to use these characters in HTML ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love the HTML for this: http://www.asciimation.co.nz/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the right Unicode characters, the old character encodings shouldn't make much odds. The tricky bit may be converting existing ASCII art into Unicode - at which point you need to know the original encoding.

The relevant code charts will be listed on the [Unicode "symbols" charts page](http://www.unicode.org/charts/symbols.html). In particular, I suspect you'll find the [box drawing](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf) and [block elements](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2580.pdf) charts useful.

You'll need to make sure that your page uses a font which contains the right characters, of course...

As an example, you can render this:

```
┌┐
└┘
```

With:

```
<pre>&#x250c;&#x2510;
&#x2514;&#x2518;</pre>
```

Not quite a proper box, but getting there...

Answer (score 3):

You can send them in the `<pre>` tags, although in XHTML you'll need to encapsulate it in `<![CDATA[[]>` I think. Be careful though, not all encodings render this correctly. For example, a lot of ASCII art designed for DOS code page 430 (US) fails over here in the UK (830). Eastern Europe suffers especially.

I think the best approach here would be to render images.

**EDIT**: Oh. You could try `&#000;`, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: Thanks, your '&#000' gave me the hint to look at unicode specifications